How to make a Continuously Transposed Conductor [CTC] model?
I want to model a product called 'continuously transposed conductor' (CTC) shown in the image, but I am quite an amateur in the program. The object is like a ladder but moves straight on a flat surface without rising. I have tried many times, but I have not been able to get a healthy and nice result. Can you help me easily model this object?

This image shows the actual state of the product


Add a plane, scale it to the correct measures of a section of a trail, delete its face (Only Faces), add three Array modifiers to get the desired mesh. Then Apply all modifiers (Ctrl A).

In edit mode, delete the appropriate groups of 4 vertices (counterclockwise the extremes top and bottom).

Alt click on an edge. Shift Alt Click on another edge, choose Bridge Edge Loop operator (Ctrl E). Repeat as needed.

When completed, add another array modifier to elongate the cable, a bevel modifier, a curve modifier targeting an appropriate curve, a subdivision surface modifier.

